# Make an URL a result of Hudson build

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have a build job which uploads results to a certain URL.

How can I have a link to that URL shown on the build page?

I've tried to create an html page with redirect and add it to the artifacts but it seems a bit weird.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per job run? Or global for the whole job?

If your link is always static (example: latest artifacts only), you can use a Sidebar link plugin. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sidebar-Link+Plugin that will place a static link per job (for all runs).

If your link changes per run, here is what I do in my environment. I update the run's description with an `<a href>` tag. The link won't show on the run page, however it works rather nicely in the build history.

[image]
Note above, the `[Debug]` and `[Release]` are unique links for each particular build.

For this, you would need Description Setter Plugin. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin. And in the plugin (it is post-build action), just write pure HTML. You can use usual environment variables in there

```
<a href="http://whatever/${BUILD_NUMBER}">Link here</a>
```

Edit: note that nowadays it isn't that easy (if at all possible) to put html in the build history description. It does work on the individual build page.

Comment: I entered just that in the description field of the Setter plugin but I don't get any link at all, not even inside each build. It just types the same thing as text for me. Do you know why that could be? it outputs as the description after the run: `<a href="http://whatever/71">Description Link here</a>` (and same as the description for the historical builds)

Comment: Found the way:

1- Install `OWASP Markup Formatter` plugin
2- In `Security - Markup Formatter - Safe HTML`

Answer (score 10):

If you want markup to be treated as such, you must enable it: Manage Jenkins > Global Security > Markup Formatter = Safe HTML

Then, for Jenkins scripted pipelines, you can simply set the `currentBuild.description` property with some HTML. Example:

```
currentBuild.description = "Click <a href='http://yourlink'>here</a>"
```

The rendered HTML will show in the build history and on the build page.

If you don't see "Safe HTML" in the Markup Formatter drop-down, you probably need to install the OWASP Markup Formatter plugin.

At the time of this post, the Blue Ocean GUI will not display HTML for build descriptions. See issue here: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-45719

This Chrome extension can serve as a workaround:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blue-ocean-description-ht/maahpenodjcdhodbonmdkfgnceddigae